# What command can I user to remove multiple/all values from a field in Youtrack

Tags: youtrack

Suppose I have a field that can contain multiple values, e.g. "Versions".
Is there a way to empty the Versions field using a YouTrack command?

At the moment I only know how to remove a specific version, e.g.:

```
Remove v123
```

If I want to remove multiple versions

```
Remove v123 Remove v456
```

I could not find a command that would empty the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting it to an empty value should help. If an empty value for your "Versions" field is "No versions", then the following command

```
Versions No versions
```

will remove all existing field values.

NOTE: the solution does not work if issues across multiple projects were selected: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-30131

Comment: Nope, sadly it doesn't work. Says "Version expected". Seems like setting an empty value only works for fields that can only have one value. Filed an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-30131 .

Comment: My problem was with the value that contained spaces. I was trying with the curly braces: `Milestone {No milestone}`, which for some reason did not work. Anyways `Milestone No milestone` works nicely.
Apparently one can even do just `No milestone` to clear the values.

Comment: NOTE: the answer does not work if issues across multiple projects were selected: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-30131